# Iterator and *Iterator type

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, variable-declaration

if I have an iterator of some container with unknown class within it, can I declare a variable of that unknown type by:

```
*Iterator unknown_type_var;
```

The unknown_type has default ctor, so that isn't the issue. But do a method like this exist ? Or is there any other method to declare a variable of a type that I have an iterator of container, which holds this type.

Comment: Did you try using `auto`?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a standard-conforming container it has a nested typedef named `value_type` that gives the type of the contained values. That typedef is also available through iterator_traits: `std::iterator_traits<iterator_type>::value_type`. And the iterator type is available as, you guessed it, a nested typedef in the container.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `value_type` available to you, and you can't use `auto` because you're not assigning right away (try to find a way to), then you could use decltype:

```
decltype(*declval<Iterator>()) unknown_type_var;
```